# PHP - Get the input's label content?

Tags: php

I'm making order page which contain a list of items and each of them has `input` to type in the amount you want to order.

The markup is like this:

```
<label for="item1">Fried Rice</label>
<input type="number" id="item1" name="item1">
...
//I have like 10 more items below
```

So basically, how do I get the string `Fried Rice` in PHP?

I'm thinking of hard-coding the input's `name` to `"fried rice"`, but it will be troublesome if someday the item name is changed.

Any solution? Thanks. I'm new to PHP by the way.

Comment: the label text node won't get posted to the server, thus you can't read it with php

Comment: On submit I need to email the Order List containing the Item name and Amount. Sorry for the lack of info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
<label for="item1">Fried Rice</label>
<input type="number" id="item1" name="item1[Fried Rice]">
```

--EDIT--

if you have a mapping of your indices (textual name) with the number then just put the index number

```
<label for="item1">Fried Rice</label>
<input type="number" id="item1" name="item1[id goes here]">
```

--EDIT-- with sample output

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [Fried Rice] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: Does that `name` is stored as array `item`? So will `item[0]` return `fried rice`?

Comment: Thanks! I never thought that PHP will see that name as Array. It works perfect for my case.

Comment: hi i updated the first answer in case you would want to go with it, `name="item1[Fried Rice]"`

Comment: @ianace Yeah, I went with `item[fried rice]`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can take as hiddne value for item like

```
<label for="item1">Fried Rice</label>
<input type="hidden" id="item1_desc" name="item1_desc" value="Fried Rice">
<input type="number" id="item1" name="item1">
```

...
please take as you need more for 10
in post you will get [item1_desc] for your label value

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: This trick seems good. But isn't there any way to get the `label` content using PHP function?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<?php $name='Fried Rice' ?>
<label for="item1"><?php echo $name ?></label>
<input type="number" id="item1" name="<?php echo $name ?>">
```

This way, if the name changes, you only need to change it in one place.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I went with ianace's answer because it is easier to scale.